# KOJS Binding Manual Subscription with Mapping Plugin

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a checkbox bound to my KOJS model.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:settings.remember">
```

I'm trying to update the database when the user changes the value of the checkbox. However, the viewmodel is updated *after* these jQuery functions:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){ });

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){ });

$("input[type='checkbox']").mouseup(function(){ });
```

To put it another way, when I peek into my viewModel inside of those functions, it will return the value of the checkbox's value *before* the user had changed it. So if the checkbox was once true and now tells me false (and displays as false), the viewModel will still say true.

Is there some other jQuery function I could use that might occur after the binding occurs? Or can you think of any other clever way to call a function after my viewModel variable has changed? Note that my current viewModel declaration is:

```
var viewModel = {};
//...get some data from AJAX calls
ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, viewModel.'+file+');
```

where file is some dynamic value (I draw my viewModel from multiple databases)

I can solve the above problem with a hacky solution below (see my answer), but RP Niemeyer's answer suggests there is a better way with manual subscriptions. So far I haven't been able to figure out defining things within my viewModel along with using the mapping plugin.

[Here's my code so far](http://jsfiddle.net/WVZxD/), though, of course, it won't work on the JSFiddle.

Comment: why do not you use `click` binding on checkbox?

Comment: @Serjio, it seems to me that my viewModel hasn't updated by the time I call that function. I need to update the data in the database within the function, so I send my viewModel over asynchronously within it. If the viewModel hasn't updated when I send it, the database doesn't get updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a good choice for this type of thing is to handle it in your view model itself.  For example, you can use a [manual subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) against `settings.remember` (if it is an observable) and trigger your database call.

```
settings = {
  remember: ko.observable(false)
};

settings.remember.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    //run your logic here
}, settings);
```

The second argument to the `subscribe` call determines the value of `this` when the function runs.

If you are really forced to interact with your field changing outside of Knockout, then you would want to hook up a "change" handler, but not until after ko.applyBindings has been called.  Then your change event handler will run after the change handler that Knockout has already added to the element. However, if your content is in a template and gets re-rendered, then your handler would be lost.

I would highly recommend using the manual subscription approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @RP Niemeyer. I'm going to look into manual subscriptions and see if it does what I need. If it does, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: if I put anything inside of my viewModel it breaks the code, and I'm not entirely sure why. I tried what you suggested, but as I anticipated it, too, results in breaking. I admit I'm not too familiar with Javascript variables and classes. Do you think you could let me know why this doesn't seem to be working, if you happen to have any idea? In the original question you'll see how I'm working with the viewModel, which was included because I thought I might get answers that wanted me to do things inside my viewModel. I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: @jmeas - can you put some code into a jsFiddle?  Even if it doesn't quite work, I can try to help you get it fixed up.

Comment: [Of course.](http://jsfiddle.net/RKwve/1/) It might be enough to show you what I'm doing. If it's not, I could link you to a working example on a website if you think that'd help you better help me. By the way, I really appreciate you taking your time to help me out.

Comment: For the record, I took a few functions out of the JS that I didn't think were that important to the issue. But their exclusion may make the code above confusing. To view the whole thing, [go here.](http://jsfiddle.net/NJrpL/)

Comment: I figured out one of the issues I was having, but not all. Now, the code doesn't break when I put things inside the viewModel, but it doesn't seem to be working with the code you've suggested. [These are the changes I made](http://jsfiddle.net/NGTUx/) (I included the line that eventually maps it, though no change was made to the mapping).

Comment: Another thought: my viewModel might have upwards of 100 variables. If I must write out each subscription like this, will I need to write several hundreds of line of code for just the subscriptions? p.s. I'm thinking this question is sufficiently complex to merit a bounty, so I might set that up if you still have time to help.

Comment: @jmeas - I am still happy to help, just not sure what your current state is.  When you mention having a lot of properties, it makes me think that you might want to go with another technique.  You really don't want to have to subscribe to every observable. Take a look at this article for how to use a computed to capture all of your dependencies: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 0):

RP Niemeyer's answer above might be much better than this, but here is my temporary fix that has solved my problem:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  viewModel.settings.remember($(this).is(":checked"));';
  //...AJAX it away
});
```